# Problems with string.format() with html file in python

Tags: python, html, string

I have hmtl template, and want to add some values there.
I was going to use sting.format module with such rule:

```
"Hello {name}! I am {years} years old".format(name = "Bob", years = "25").
```

So I have written such test

```
x = open(source_folder + "template.html", 'r')
  template = x.read()
  template.format(tester = "John")
  studio_html = open(studio_folder + "/" + studio_name + ".html", 'w')
  studio_html.write(template)
```

The beginning of the file is:

```
  {tester}
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1  /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta ....
```

The full version of the file is here - http://bit.ly/R4zxQ6

I run the script, and it gives me errors, which tell that the html file contains other "{ }" containers... what can you suggest to do to avoid this problem?

Best regards, Sasha.

Comment: to render templates, take a look at [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) or [django's templating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) system. Your problem is with javascript blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been suggested, a real templating module would give you the best flexibility.  However, it is possible to do it how you originally intended.  To do so, you can escape the curly braces that should not be used for string formatting.  For example, you would want to modify this:

```
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
```

as this:

```
function MM_swapImgRestore() {{ //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}}
```

When doubled/escaped like this, the format/vformat method will ignore them while parsing.  Replacement fields should still have only one set of braces, e.g. `{tester}`.

Comment: Sorry - I think this is bad advice. Not only is it going to double up any string literals containing `{` or `}` (unless you're suggesting editing by hand), depending on the language inside the code, it may well introduce new scope blocks or have other undesired effects in parsing. Then you've got serious head scratching later.

Comment: I wasn't advising him to do it this way.  Just answering the question that was asked.  I wouldn't choose this method, myself.  However, if he's creating these templates himself from scratch, he has the option of pre-processing the HTML to do the brace escaping, and then add the template braces in afterwards.  And maybe he has some reason not to use a module outside the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `format` - you're much better off using a templating engine meant for XML/HTML (or just text replacement in general) - have a look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

You could "roll-your-own" using regular expressions and choosing delimiter characters that aren't likely to appear in HTML - popular ones are {{ some_value }} - but templating engines handle this for you.

(A light-weight alternative is using string.Template at http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings and changing the delimiter)

`jinja2` is quite easy to get started with, but "other products are available"!

Comment: Thanks! I'll use similar string replacements in this project, but then I'll look deeply into python templating engines!

Answer (score 1):

Python string replacement should help here.

I had to put month and year in a html but .format or % did not help and was seeing issues after trying those, thought of escaping the { by using {{ or { but html code was very big and had 500+ '{' characters.

so, updated the html with a string 'month_year' as below:

```
body = """<html>
.
.
.
<p>month_year</p>
.
.
.
</html>
"""
```

body = body.replace('month_year',datetime.date.today().strftime("%B %Y"))

This worked for me